# ?p=index OR ?p=about on website urls

Tags: javascript, html, css, url, web

I've been noticing some websites have this characteristic in the url. Instead of `website.com/index.html` they have something like `website.com/?p=index` or `website.com/?p=about`...

Can anyone help me identify how to do this? or why I should/shouldn't?

Thanks y'all

Comment: This is using POST/GET data to dynamically change the content of a webpage. Look at tutorials regarding Dynamic websites with PHP.

Comment: This is a get parameter in url this help to share the url and this way they decide which page should be load...

Answer (score 1):

That is called [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). Used to send data to server. Server gets that parameters and perform some logic and can change data on page based on this parameters

Answer (score 0):

These are *technically* friendly URLs. The basic principle is `domain.com/` is a mask for `domain.com/index.php` or `domain.com/default.php`.

To do this, use this--remember this is very basic illustration of the concept.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_GET['p'])&&!empty($_GET['p'])){
    $page = trim($_GET['p']);
    switch($page){
        case 'about':
          include 'about.php';
          break;
        case 'team':
          include 'team.php';
          break;
        default:
          include 'home.php'; // or 404 page!
          break;
    }

} else {
    // when `p` is not set, show homepage
    include 'home.php';
}

?>
```

Comment: thanks for that Adam...

Where would I call such a function?

Answer (score 0):

If you learn PHP and SQL, you will realize how it works!
Like:
URL: example.com/index.php?firstname=Charles&lastname=Craft

```
<?php
echo "My First Name is: " . $_GET['firstname'] . " and my Last Name is: " . $_GET['lastname'];
?>
```

Result:

```
My First Name is: Charles and my Last Name is: Craft
```

And it is also a Query String that used to send data to Server.
We can also use it in AJAX To load SQL Table without refreshing the browser.

Learn: AJAX, SQL, and PHP

Comment: Notice that `index.html` won't work, you need `index.php` but only if you didn't rewrite the index.php to index.html.

Comment: oops, sorry I forgot :)